# Laravel tables removid id column

Tags: php, laravel

Is that possible to remove `id` column from laravel tables?

`Example`

In my settings table I really don't need `id` column there will be basic columns and data `1 row only`, maximum user will edit them so nothing to add(store).

## Explanation

My question is about model binding

1. for eg. when we remove `timestamps` we'll add `public $timestamps =
   false;` should we do the same for id?
2. Since it's increment will cause error then or not?
   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-migration-removing-incrementsid-makes-table-un-updatable

Comment: Are you talking about UI or database?

Comment: database.......

Comment: do you try it by removing `$table->increments('id');` line from your migration file?

Comment: yes i removed that, but my question is about model binding, for eg. when we remove timestamps we'll add `public $timestamps = false;` should we do the same for id?

Comment: since it's increment will cause error then or not? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-migration-removing-incrementsid-makes-table-un-updatable

Comment: set `$incrementing = false;`, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this migration :

```
class CreateSampleTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tablename', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('filed_name');
        });
    }
}
```

This will not create an `id` for your `tablename`. You don't necessarily need a primary key on every table in Laravel.

For if you need to remove a specific column which is already there in the table, use:

```
$table->dropColumn('field_name');
```

For model binding, use:

```
protected $primaryKey = null;

public $incrementing = false;
```

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column
>   named id. You may define a protected $primaryKey property to override
>   this convention.
>
> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing
>   integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be
>   cast to an int automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or
>   a non-numeric primary key you must set the public $incrementing
>   property on your model to false. If your primary key is not an
>   integer, you should set the protected $keyType property on your model
>   to string.

Source: The [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models)

Comment: Create an Eloquent model for a legacy table that has no primary key by this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that in your migration.

```
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->dropPrimary('id');
    $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your migration file you can delete the id column;

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id'); // delete this
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

in my pivot tables, I don't use an increments id column and I never encountered with any error